# removing chart series from compare charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Trying to remove the one of the chart from the compare charts contains 5 charts series.

There were five check-boxes and each check-boxes on check add the charts...and if the checkbox uncheck than the chart get remove. i tried for chart.series[2] but if button 1 ,2 and 3 were checks the chart display all three and if uncheck second checkbox than chart 2 does not goes off instead show all three and same goes with other 3,4 and 5.

```
$('li').click(function (evt) { if ($(this).attr("class") == "BtnA" || $(this).attr("class") == "BtnB" || $(this).attr("class") == "BtnC" || $(this).attr("class") == "BtnD" || $(this).attr("class") == "BtnE") {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            if ($(this).addClass("selected")) {

                switch ($(this).attr("class")) {
                    case "BtnA selected": testing_name = "test1"; names = 'testname1';
                        break;
                    case "BtnB selected": testing_name = "test2"; names = 'testname2';
                        break;
                    case "BtnC selected": testing_name = "test3"; names = 'testname3';
                        break;
                    case "BtnD selected": testing_name = "test4"; names = 'testname4';
                        break;
                    case "BtnE selected": testing_name = "test5"; names = 'testname5';
                        break;
                }
                chart(testing_name, names);
            }else if ($(this).attr("class") == "BtnA selected" || $(this).attr("class") == "BtnB selected" || $(this).attr("class") == "BtnC selected" || $(this).attr("class") == "BtnD selected" || $(this).attr("class") == "BtnD selected") {
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
                            $('li').each(function () {

                             $('#container').charts('tested').series[2].hide();
                            }
```

and the function call for chart();

```
               function chart(testing_name, names) {

        $(function () {

            var seriesOptions = [],
        yAxisOptions = [],
        seriesCounter = 0;

            if (data == 0) {
                series_names = ["data"];
                jsonfilename = ["datajson"];
            }

            data++;
            series_names.push(names);

            jsonfilename.push(testing_name);


            $.each(series_names, function (i, name) {

                $.getJSON(jsonfilename[i] + ".txt", function (data) {
                    seriesOptions[i] = {
                        name: name,
                        data: data
                    };
                    seriesCounter++;

                    if (seriesCounter == series_names.length) {
                        createChart();
                    }
                });
            });



            // create the chart when all data is loaded
            function createChart() {

                $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

                    rangeSelector: {
                        inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480,
                        selected: 4
                    },

                    yAxis: {
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function () {
                                return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
                            }
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 2,
                            color: 'silver'
                        }]
                    },

                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            compare: 'percent'
                        }
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    },

                    series: seriesOptions
                });
            }


        });

    }
```

can you please provide any reference code for this to achieve.

Thanks & Regards,
ShailShin

Comment: what does the HTML of the charts look like?

Comment: does look like http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare - Highstock demo - Compare multiple series

Comment: I am finding it hard to visualize what your page looks like. In any event, you should just add an event listener to the checkboxes and remove/hide the appropriate table

Comment: Perhaps you can demonstrate with a jsfiddle.net

Comment: So you need to destroy series or chart? If you need to hide series, you can call [hide()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.hide) funciton